# I cannot login to the Netgear genie/router dashboard

Tags: wireless-router

I just bought a brand new Netgear N300 router (model WNR2000v5) today. I have followed the steps in the instruction manual to set it up. Once I get to step 5 I can't go any further. It says the username and password are 'admin' and 'password' yet when I enter it it just says incorrect. I called Netgear support and they had me reset the router a million times then basically said "oh, well we can't help you" and hung up on me.
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: have you tried `admin` as both the username and password?

Comment: Two things.  1. You may not be getting connected to the router you think you're connecting to, so isolate your computer and router and try again.  2. If the default credentials don't work and support can't help, then take it back and get a new one.

Comment: Netgear support will ask you for 79 dollars for 6 months of support and then access it for you to install your firmware.  It's how they're conning people to generate more income: their firmware corrupts itself after your software warranty expires.

Answer (score 1):

go to IE and type 192.168.1.1 and Netgear pops up. If you're asked for login and password that can be found on the router itself. It's usually admin and basicocean with a number, like 730. You can make password and login changes and many other changes while in genie online. This is my second and I like it better than the others and reasonable priced too. Hope this helps. 
Remember that the beginning box if it pops up doesn't change. It will be admin an basicocean, check your router first And make sure you remember your login and password for Genie.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried accessing it without registration?

```
http://www.mywifiext.net/start_repeater.htm
```